# Run partially build of Makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've the following `makefile` which is look like following

```
PROJ_DIR := $(CURDIR)
all: pre app app1 app2 app3
apps = app app1 app2 app3 
pre:
  mkdir temp
app:
    cd PROJ_DIR/app ; npm install

app1:
    cd PROJ_DIR/app1 ; npm install
...
#Need to wait to app1...n to finish the install process in order to proceed and zip all the app installed artifacts
build:$(apps)
     #zip all the apps artifacts

clean:build
    rm -rf test
```

Now when I run this with `make` **everything is working as expected**. 
The problem is that I want to run partial build like

`make -j1 pre app1 build clean` (in the sequence only `app1` should run and not `app2 app3` etc ) here I've a problem since I've the `apps` pre-requestie(hint from Renaud ) which helps to wait when I execute the whole the make with `make` but if I want to run it partially it still run them all (all the apps) , is there a trick which can help in both for the execution type ?

Comment: `build` depends on `$(apps)`, which expands to `app app1 app2 app3`. If `build` can do its job without those targets, then why are they dependencies? You can just remove them. Conversely, if `build` actually needs those targets to be built first, how are you expecting this to work?

Comment: @Thomas - build needs that, it cannot start if all the apps execution not finished , therefore I ask if there is some trick here

Comment: I'm just guessing now at what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) are what you need. Something like: `build: | $(apps)`.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks, I've tried it (add the `|` before the apps)  with command `make -j1 pre app1 build clean` but still I see that `app` is running even I put in the command `app1`

Comment: @Thomas - maybe I can declare the `apps = app app1 app2 app3` with condition ? anything else ? if I remove the requisite `$(apps)` it work for partial build

Comment: Then why is it a prerequisite in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas - because before I've added it when I run just `make` it `doesnt` wait to all the `app1 ...appsN` to finished the process( here is just echo but its more time consuming process like installing dep)  before starting the next command (which is `build` for example)

Comment: @Thomas - If I remove it the process will build in wrong order in case or running just `make`

Comment: @Thomas - I dont care if the apps 1...n will build in parallel , (its better if they do that -im also handling it )but when all the appsN processes will finished just then start the build (which zip's all the build artifacts ) it cannot start before...

Comment: @RaynD Let's start by the end: your `build` target. What happens if its recipe (`cd $(PROJ_DIR) npm install` which, I guess is more likely `cd $(PROJ_DIR); npm install`) is executed but only `app1` has been built? Does it crash? Does it install only `app1`? Something else?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - this is just example , but for your question it will not break. lets say that inside the `apps` im running `npm install` for `each app` and the `build` wait them to `finish` and build are` zipping` the apps `artifacts`. so in this case I will get zip that not have all the artifacts since the build process start before all the apps finsihed to install dep

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - please see my last update\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand all details but there is one important thing to consider: make does exactly what you tell it to do, no more, no less (hopefully). So, if you tell it that `build` depends on all your apps you cannot expect make to do `build` before it also did all apps. It's that simple. It's what

```
build: $(apps)
```

says: `build` depends on `$(apps)` or, in other words, it is **impossible** to do `build` before having done `$(apps)`.

If you want to build with only one app, you need another target than `build`... or you need to change the definition of the `apps` make variable. And guess what, it's probably the easiest thing to do because make let's you do this on the command line:

```
$ make apps='app1' pre build clean
```

or, if you want to build and pack only `app1` and `app2`:

```
$ make apps='app1 app2' pre build clean
```

By default the variables that are assigned on the command line take precedence over the definitions from inside the Makefile. Executing `make apps='app1' pre build clean` will do exactly the same as if you edit the Makefile to change the definition of `apps` and then execute `make pre build clean`.

Comment: ohh you are genius, This is exactly what I need ,let me check

Comment: @RaynD: if your Makefile is correctly written, with all dependencies correctly expressed, no, you don't need `-j1`. Else, your Makefile is what we call `not parallel safe` and you will have to use `-j1`. But without looking at the complete Makefile we cannot tell whether it is parallel safe or not.